# SSH Unknown TTY Error Message

Tags: go, ssh, network-programming, cisco

When trying to run the command `ssh user@ip 'command'`, I keep receiving this error: `can't get tty settingscan't set orig mode`. I have tried googling this and searching here but have not found anything referring to this message. I am trying to automate connecting to a Cisco wireless access point (2800 model) using Golang to run a command then exit, but this message pops up each time. I can log in normally using `ssh user@ap_ip`, but using the shorthand `ssh user@ap_ip 'command'` or trying the equivalent in Golang gives the error message above. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: `ssh user@ap_ip` and `ssh user@ap_ip 'command'` are different things.  Running ssh with `-vvv` will give you more information about how the commands are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh without explicit command given will allocate a terminal while ssh with a command given will by default not. It looks like the command you execute needs a terminal. In this case use the `-t` option, i.e. `ssh -t user@ip command`. From [the documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

```
-t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute 
        arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
        very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t 
        options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```